# sdk request: how to get all headers?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/request.html

How to get all headers?

I cant see "Location" or "Set-Cookie" from request. But i see it by firebug.

Answer (score 4):

The `request` module is a slight wrapper around the XHR implementation. Using the [net/xhr](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/net/xhr.html) module exposes the standard [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object, which allows you to call methods like `setRequestHeader`, `getAllResponseHeaders` and `getResponseHeader`

Comment: You still won't be able to see the "Location" header, as this header is only set by the redirecting request, not the final (redirected) one.

Comment: mybe i am stupid but this cant work
    
<!-- language: lang-js -->
    var {Cc, Ci, Cu} = require('chrome');
    function reqListener () {
      console.log(this.responseText);
    };

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.onload = reqListener;
    oReq.open("get", "http://ya.ru", true);
    oReq.send();

Comment: The `net/xhr` module was changed recently to use the Web API implementation of XHR, this allows using all the features available in a "normal" browser XHR: (https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/commit/f8729d9ee98ca84e47cbe5fa06621c26f39984cc) Unfortunately, this is still in Beta (v24), but will be released in 2 weeks, allowing you to use `onload` -- you can use `onreadystatechange` in the mean time for v23 (examples in tests: https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/master/test/test-xhr.js#L66)

Also, in your example, there are some syntax errors and you need `http://` in URL